# PyQt5 classes, methods and properties now showing in Eclipe in AutoComplete, standard class names showing errors but the program runs

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete

I am running Python 3.4 and Qt5, the IDE is Eclipse with PyDev
Here is what I am seeing

[image]

and

[image]

The program runs fine but ...I am trying to learn how to access model data using indexes and the Autocomplete function is not working at all with the PyQt5 classes as shown above
The Pygrpahviz module is also working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time figuring out how to integrate eclipse, pydev, and pyqt5 on linux today.

## Eclipse, PyQt5, and PyDev on Linux

1. Install python v3.6
2. Install eclipse from eclipse.org
3. In eclipse, click Help->Install New Software
4. Click Add...
5. Add in software source "http://www.PyDev.org/updates" to the available software sources
6. Call it PyDev
7. Click on PyDev checkbox
8. Install it by clicking Next
9. [Download PyQt5](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)
10. [Download SIP](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download)
11. Install SIP first
12. Install PyQt5
13. Reconfigure eclipse to use PyQt5
14. Click on Window→Preferences→PyDev→Interpreters→Python Interpreters
15. Click on Advanced Auto-Config
16. Rename interpreter to “python3.6”
17. Click on Libraries tab
18. Click on New Folder
19. Add in “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins”
20. Add in “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/libexec”
21. Add in “/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin”
22. Click Apply
23. Click Apply and Close
24. Restart eclipse
25. Profit!

This will allow you to get the tab code completion in eclipse when developing pyqt5 applications.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to changing the python interpreter from Python 3.6 to Python 3.5
I had to close Eclipse and open it again. Now everything is back to normal
I still can't undderstand why the program was running fine though